# Error al intentar hacer una pila

Tags: c#, array, visual-studio-2017, pilas

Lo que ocurre es que estoy intentando hacer un windows form que almacene datos en forma de Pila sin embargo cuando intento mostrar los datos que se agregan solo me muestra 0 y no los muestra en el `Textbox`. Este vendría siendo el código del `Form`:

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    int[] lapila;
    int tope ;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int txt = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            lapila = new int[5];
                 lapila[tope] = txt;
                      tope++;
                        textBox1.Clear();    

    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int extrae = lapila[tope];
        tope--;

    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lapila.Length; i++)
        {
            textBox2.Text += lapila[i].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

`Button1` es agregar al tope de la pila, `Button2` vendría siendo para extraer del tope y el `Button3` es el usado para mostrar el contenido de la pila sin embargo no lo muestra.

Comment: 0 o solamente el ultimo que ingresaste?

Comment: a mi me lo muestra.. solamente que hay un error de logica en boton1 y por eso ves cualquier cosa.

Comment: Al hacer lapila = new int[5];, esta haciendo una nueva pila cada vez que apretas el boton1. De ahi que veas cualquier cosa al querer mostrar la pila.

Comment: En ese caso como debo inicializar la pila? se supone que debo darle un tamaño al vector seria afuera del boton?

Comment: ¿Es un ejercicio para un trabajo escolar? lo digo porque en c# (y.net en general) ya hay una clase para manejar una pila, se llama Stack: var pila = new Stack<int>();

Comment: Se que hay una clase llamada stack en la cual solo usaria el push para añadir sin embargo tengo que hacerlo sin usar esa clase solo usando un vector(asi me lo pusieron para resolver).

Comment: La pila la tenes que inicializar una sola vez.. digamos al abrir el form? y despues en cada pop y push tenes que controlar que se puede hacer. no podes hacer pop de una pila vacia, y no podes hacer push a una pila llena...

Answer (score 1):

La inicializacion del array debes realizarlo en el `Load` del form, si lo haces en el evento del boton estas perdiendo lo que hayas ingresado porque inicializas la variable en cada evento

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int[] lapila;
    private int tope ;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Form1_Load(...)
    {
        lapila = new int[5];
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int txt = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text);

        lapila[tope] = txt;
        tope++;

        textBox1.Clear();    

    }
```

Para visualizar los valores podrias usar

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox2.Text = string.Join(", ", lapila.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Hola Leandro sin embargo para visualizar los valores se me esta pidiendo usar un for o esta es la unica forma de visualizarlos? Al usar el for solamente me muestra el ultimo elemento añadido. Otra pregunta que parametros se le daria al Form1_Load? se dejaria vacia no? Disculpa preguntar tanto...

Comment: Puedes usar un for, pero es mas simple unir los valores con el string.Join(). Puedes usar un `foreach(var item in lapila)`

Comment: foreach ( var item in lapila)
            {

                textBox2.Text = lapila[tope].ToString();


            } estoy intentando añadiendolos de esa manera sin embargo solo muestra 1 apesar de que añado mas de un item

Comment: no seria `foreach ( var item in lapila) { textBox2.Text = item.ToString(); }` la variable lapila es la que estas iterando, con el foreach no necesitas un index poque la vaiable que indicas item ya toma su contenido

Comment: Si pero ahi lo que termina haciendo es mostrar el ultimo elemento de la pila no la pila completa. Como podria concatenar dentro del for?

Comment: textBox2.Text += item.ToString(); habia olvidado poner el +=